# How to close Cursor opened in Adapter class?

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor

In my app I have an activity showing images in gridView. So I used an Adapter class extending BaseAdapter. In that adapter class I opened a cursor and return images from the getView() method.

So now my question is where should I close the cursor as I am getting exception. I cannot use startManagingCursor() as it is deprecated. Any other solution will be appreciated.

My onCreate method

```
public void onCreate(Bundle bundle){
    super.onCreate(bundle);
    setContentView(R.layout.splitted_grid);
    System.out.println("started new splittedimageactivity");
    //splittedBitmaps = getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra("splitted_images");
    int size = getIntent().getIntExtra("image_numbers", 0);
    int width = getIntent().getIntExtra("width", 0);
    int height = getIntent().getIntExtra("height", 0);
    gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.image_grid_view);
    SplittedImageAdapter s = new SplittedImageAdapter(this, size, width, height);
    gridView.setAdapter(s);
    gridView.setNumColumns((int) Math.sqrt(size));//splittedBitmaps.size()));
    s.close();// This causes exception trying to re-open already closed cursor. If I remove this, then exception is your cursor is not closed, call close() explicitly 
}
```

My adapter class

```
public class SplittedImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

private Context mContext;
//private List<Bitmap> mSplittedBitmaps;
public ViewGroup mParentView = null;
private int noOfImages, imageWidth, imageHeight;
private Cursor mCursor;

public SplittedImageAdapter(Context c, int size, int w, int h){
    mContext = c;
    noOfImages = size;
    imageWidth = w;
    imageHeight = h;
    DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(c);
    db.open();
    mCursor = db.getAllImages();
    System.out.println(mCursor+"cursor opened");

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return noOfImages;//mSplittedBitmaps.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;//mSplittedBitmaps.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    mParentView = parent;
    ImageCell imageView = null;
    if(convertView == null){
        imageView = new ImageCell(mContext);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(imageWidth-4, imageHeight-4));//65,65));//SplittedImageActivity.splittedBitmaps.get(position).getWidth()-4, SplittedImageActivity.splittedBitmaps.get(position).getHeight()-4));
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
    }else{
        imageView = (ImageCell) convertView;
    }
    imageView.mCellNumber = position;
    imageView.mGrid = (GridView) mParentView;
    imageView.setId(position);
    if(position == noOfImages-1){//SplittedImageActivity.splittedBitmaps.size()-1 == position){
        imageView.mEmpty = true;
        imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.cell_empty);
    }
    else{
        //System.out.println(mCursor.getCount());
        mCursor.moveToPosition(position);
        Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCursor.getString(4));//"/sdcard/Android/data/com.softtrends.puzzle/files/Pictures/image"+position+".jpg");
        imageView.setImageBitmap(b);//SplittedImageActivity.splittedBitmaps.get(position));
        imageView.mEmpty = false;
    }
    imageView.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) mContext);
    imageView.setOnLongClickListener((OnLongClickListener) mContext);
    return imageView;
}

public void close(){
    mCursor.close();
}
}
```

Comment: I'd call Cursor.close() after I was sure I had received all data I needed, or make a wrapper method on my BaseAdapter subclass called close() that calls my cursor's close method. I'm not sure how you've set up your app or BaseAdapter subclass, so I can't help further.

Comment: it depends on how you getting this cursor ... if it's from ConetntProvider you can use http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/CursorLoader.html in other case you can close cursor in onDestroy of activity

Comment: @Selvin The cursor object is local to the subclass of BaseAdapter, how wold I close that in onDestroy of the Activity associating with that adapter?

Comment: if you're using Cursors why don't you use CursorAdapter as base for your adapter ... it takes Cusros as parameter of constructor so in case of use CursorAdapter you should create cursor in Activity where Adapter is created ... it contains swapCursor() method so you dont need to create new adapter in case if you do requery ...

Comment: Selvin's idea is the ideal solution to this problem

Comment: @Selvin Yes I will try this, but by seeing the code can you suggest anything without changing the code?

Comment: ok so call close of adpater in onDestroy of activity but this code looks messy ...
after analizing it(code), it seems like you want to have one more row that cursor(i think this aditional row is acting like add button) well it works but ... i think that  you shouldn't do this and use CurosrAdapter instead (footer of the list view could act like "add button") on item click listeners could be set to ListView not to ImageView ...

Comment: @Selvin thanks for your cooperation, I will try to use CursorAdapter.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you are not exclusively calling close() method.

Do it before returning imageView in getView() method of Adapter and remove `s.close()` as `s` is an adapter and not a cursor.